# displaying a progress indicator in Service

Tags: android

I have a service that I use to upload some files to a Server using Http. I want to display a progress indicator as the files are being uploaded. Initially, I used the startForeground() method to display a simple notification during the transfer process. I would now like to use a progress indicator like the one shown while downloading Apps from the Google Play store. I followed the example snipped as shown on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView

But implementing it in my Service is causing a RuntimeException. The code inside my Service class is as follows:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Thread myThr = new Thread(new MyThreadClass());

    myThr.start();

    return START_STICKY;

}

public class SendSelectedNew extends Thread{

    public void run(){
        try{
            if(fileSize()>0){
                int fileSize = getSize();
                for(int i = 0; i<fileSize;i++){
                    setNote(sizeOfTheList, i);
                    startForeground(1339, note);
                    mNotifyManager.notify(1339, note);
     /*Code to upload files to my Server

     */             
            }
                MyService mySer = MyService.this;

                mySer.stopForeground(true);
                mySer.stopSelf();

            }               
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(connection!=null){
                connection.disconnect();                    
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
 }

public void setNote(int fileSize, int progress){
    note = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentText("Sending files").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sendreceive).setContentTitle("MYApp").setProgress(fileSize, progress, false).build();
    note.flags|= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I not allowed to show a progress indicator from a Service? I'm not getting any logs in Logcat for my Application but this is what I get on the Debug pane

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread$ServiceArgsData) line: 2782 
ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ServiceArgsData) line: 152    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1385  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5328    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1102 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 869 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Can you post the log for the error?

Comment: That's not "the log for the error". That's a useless bit of output from Eclipse. Allow Eclipse to run past the point of this exception, then use LogCat to get the complete stack trace.

Comment: Are you updating files parallely or sequentially?

Comment: Thanks guys Problem solved :) Thanks commonsware, I was able to pin-point the issue. I was missing a parameter in one of the methods in the service class. Picked up the issue when I forced Eclipse to resume the suspended Application

Answer (score 0):

Do not call your setNote method from a thread but implement a listener in your service:

```
public interface ProgressListener{
    public abstract void onProgressChange(int progress);
}

public class MyService implements ProgressListener{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChange(int progress){
        //update your UI, launch notification or whatever you want
    }
}
```

then in your thread init define your listener:

```
ProgressListener myListener = mySer;
```

and call the onProgressChange in your loop:

```
myListener.onProgressChange(i);
```

Comment: Cheers mate! My problem is solved. The issue was in one of the parameters that I missing in the Service class. Your answer looks interesting though, I'll give it a go anyways and see if works as well :)